# how to shuffle JButton with image?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, shuffle

error here :

```
for(int h = 0; h <= picture; h++)
{
      list.add(picture[h]);
      picture.addActionListener(this);

}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

this is my full code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class PrimeMinister extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Timer t; //declare timer
 ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Creates new form PrimeMinister
 */
public PrimeMinister() {
     super("Prime Minister");
    initComponents();





}
private int currCounter; //declare for boolean true and continue another statement

private void wrongChoice(int counter){
    switch(counter){
        case 0: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 1st Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
        case 1: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 2nd Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
        case 2: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 3rd Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
        case 3: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 4th Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
        case 4: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 5th Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
        case 5: jTextField1.setText("Wrong!!   Please try again!   Who is the 6th Prime Minister of Malaysia?"); break;
    }  
}// wrong choice if click different Prime Minister

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lbl_Timer = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Find the Prime Minister of Malaysia");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 2, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Can you list the Prime Ministers of Malaysia in chronological order?");

    jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\najib.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setName("jButton[1]"); // NOI18N
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\T_PakLah.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setName("jButton[2]"); // NOI18N
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\tarahman.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setName("jButton[3]"); // NOI18N
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\Tun_Hussein_Onn_portrait.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setName("jButton[4]"); // NOI18N
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\TunMahathir4th.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setName("jButton[5]"); // NOI18N
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user_PC\\Desktop\\PM\\TunRazak2nd.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jButton6.setText("jButton6");
    jButton6.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    jButton6.setName("jButton[6]"); // NOI18N
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton7.setText("New Game");
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton8.setText("Quit");
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText(" To start the game:  Clicks on the image of the first Prime Minister of Malaysia!");

    jLabel4.setText("Timer:");

    lbl_Timer.setText("00");
    lbl_Timer.setToolTipText("");
    lbl_Timer.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lbl_TimerActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton9.setText("Reset");
    jButton9.setToolTipText("");
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lbl_Timer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(127, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton7)
                .addComponent(jButton8)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(lbl_Timer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton9))
            .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void lbl_TimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(currCounter == 1){
     jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Tun Abdul Razak 2nd Prime Minister of Malaysia");
     currCounter = 2; //continue next 3rd Prime Minister
    }
    else {
       wrongChoice(currCounter);//refer to switch case statement
    }
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    this.dispose();

}                                        

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    for(int h=0;h<=picture;h++)
    {
        list.add(picture[h]);
        picture.addActionListener(this);

    }
   Collections.shuffle(list);
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     if(currCounter == 3){
     currCounter = 4; //continue next 5th Prime Minister
     jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Tun DR. Mahathir 4th Prime Minister of Malaysia");
     }
     else 
     {
     wrongChoice(currCounter);//refer to switch case statement
     }
}                                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     if(currCounter == 5){
     currCounter = 6; //Final Prime Minister
    jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Najib Razak 6th Prime Minister of Malaysia");
    t.stop();
     }
     else 
     {
      wrongChoice(currCounter); //refer to switch case statement
     }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(currCounter == 4){
     currCounter = 5; //continue next 6th Prime Minister
    jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Abdullah Ahmad Badawi 5th Prime Minister of Malaysia");
    }
    else
    {
        wrongChoice(currCounter);//refer to switch case statement
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     currCounter = 0;
    System.out.println(currCounter);    // debug: show current pm
     t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
     int currTime = 0;
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           lbl_Timer.setText(currTime + "");  
           currTime ++; 
       }
   });

   t.start();
    if(currCounter == 0){
     currCounter = 1;//continue next 2nd Prime Minister
     jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Tunku Abdul Rahman 1st Prime Minister of Malaysia");
    }
    else{
       wrongChoice(currCounter);//refer to switch case statement
    }
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(currCounter == 2){
     currCounter = 3;//continue next 4rd Prime Minister

     jTextField1.setText("Correct!! this is Tun Hussein Onn 3rd Prime Minister of Malaysia");
    }
    else{
       wrongChoice(currCounter);//refer to switch case statement
    }
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextField1.setText("");
    lbl_Timer.setText("");

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimeMinister.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimeMinister.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimeMinister.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PrimeMinister.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */

   // Original array



























    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PrimeMinister().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField lbl_Timer;
// End of variables declaration                   
private JButton picture[]= {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, jButton4, 
jButton5, jButton6};

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Reduce this to a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the error, but probably it is caused by

```
for(int h=0;h<=picture;h++) //this line. picture is array
```

I guess you intended to do

```
for(int h=0;h<picture.length;h++)
{
//..rest of code
```